# Django-cms, children variable in template, page navigation doesn't show in newer version

Tags: django, django-templates, django-cms

I'm trying to run project using Django-cms 3.6.0. It was created using Django-cms 2.3.8, I'm trying to use the old code. In this new version the menu with subpages links doesn't appear. `children` variable in template doesn't seem to contain anything.
I expect it to show links to 4 subpages of a page. I've added pages manually in admin UI in new version of django-cms.
`subbase.html`:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load menu_tags cms_tags %}
...
{% block left_menu %}
<nav id="lMenu">
 {% show_menu 1 1 0 1 "menu/sub_menu.html" %}
 {% block left_content %}{% endblock left_content %}
</nav>
{% endblock left_menu %}
```

`sub_menu.html`:

```
{% load menu_tags %}
<ul class="subMenu">
 {% for child in children %}
 <li><a href="{{ child.attr.redirect_url|default:child.get_absolute_url }}" title="{{ child.get_menu_title }}">{{ child.get_menu_title }}</a></li>
 {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I've checked in database, using `manage.py shell`, that those pages has child pages:

```py
from cms.models.pagemodel import Page
pages = Page.object.all()
children = pages[2].get_descendant_pages()
```

And now, e.g., calling `pages[2].get_menu_title(), children[0].get_menu_title()` returns expected proper names of the pages, as added through UI.

I haven't found much about this children variable in docs. Should this still work this way in 3.6? What is the proper way to refer to child pages in template?

Comment: Does `1 1 0 1` correspond do how you've built your tree? If you remove those args does it show children? The `children` context variable is correct; http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.6.x/topics/menu_system.html#menu-system-logic

Comment: Yes, this corresponds to my tree. I've found that there were something wrong with language settings.

Answer (score 0):

I've found, that I had something wrong with language settings. Menu with subpages links started to appear after I:

- used i18n_patterns in main project urls.py file
- added CMS_LANGUAGES in settings.py according to docs http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#cms-languages
- added pages in both languages through cms admin page. Before I had page in only one language.

Can't remember exactly which one fixed issue with submenu. 
Also maybe something were wrong with urls handling, I used django apps urls from urls.py instead of cms.urls.